# HTML Flask button does not redirect to home URL properly

Tags: python, html, flask

I have two HTML buttons. One to start a task and the other to stop it:

starts:

```
<form action="localhost:5000/data" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="Start Data Collection" value="Start Data Collection"/>
</form>
```

stops:

```
<form action="localhost:5000/stop" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="Stop" value="Stop"/>
</form>
```

I am using flask to build my web server. The flask code to handle my start button is:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def recvdata():
    message = {"message":"start_socket"}
    messageQueue.put(message)
    return redirect("/")
```

and stop:

```
@app.route('/stop', methods=['POST'])
def stop_task():
    message = {'message':'stop'}
    messageQueue.put(message)
    return redirect("/")
```

Both buttons are meant to redirect back to the home page after processing. The start button does without issue. The stop button redirects to `localhost:5000/localhost:5000/stop` and I can't seem to figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are determining a link, if the link does not start with the protocol or `//`, it will be appended to the current path.

Therefore, instead of `action="localhost:5000/stop"` just set it to `action="//localhost:5000/stop"`, forcing it to use the same protocol you are using right now (http or https).

The same should be done to the `action="localhost:5000/data"`, becoming `action="//localhost:5000/data"`